# Subversive Plugin Eclipse sync with FTP?

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, ftp, subversive

in my new job I'm the developer for the Joomla! CMS. Since it is using PHP I wanted to work with eclipse (like in my apprenticeship) with the latest Keplar build + the PHP Development Tools. To have some revision control I wanted to use the Subversive Plugin so I installed it and the connector.

I got access to the systemfiles via FTP (SSH) so I tried to just add the URL as repository URL but somehow it doesnt work. I used the exact URL e.g. http://www.test.joomla.de and the correct login (using this combination also works fine in filezilla for example) but every try results in:

```
Get repository folder children operation failed.
svn: Repository moved temporarily to '/'; please relocate
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/'
```

Do I have to do anything on serverside to make it work or is it okay the way I tried?

Im sorry for those questions if they are bad, but in my apprenticeship the subversive was only local and was already installed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no one? Or am I just overseeing something :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Administrator failed in the installation in giving me the wrong IP, so I couldnt interact with the server.

Comment: This answer is unlikely to help future visitors.  Would you kindly elaborate?  (That you are taking the time to come back to answer your own *is* appreciated!)

Comment: Well yeah sorry it was just a small mistake by the administrator, sorry for asking this question. I tried to delete it but I ddint found where to do so